# Is the notation $f(x)′$ the same as $f′(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

$$f(x)=f(−x)⇒(f(x))′=(f(−x))′⇒f′(x)=−f′(−x)⇒f′$$

My question arises from this procedure.

Comment: Boy, is this bad notation.  I wouldn't try to decipher it.  Just work the proof from scratch (it's not too bad).

Comment: To avoid confusion, I'd suggest defining $g(x)=-x$.  So your assumption is that $f\circ g(x)=f(x)$.  Now take $\frac d{dx}$ of both sides of that and use the chain rule.

Comment: you seem to comment that if $f$ is even, then $f'$ is odd. I do not see how this relates to your question in the title. I don't think the notation $f(x)'$ is used.

Comment: @Mirko However, $(f(x))'$ is used, and is handy, but dangerous (easy to confuse with $f'(x)$).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, $(f(x))'$ means $f'(x)$.

The tricky thing to remember, though, is that $f'(-x) \neq (f(-x))'$ in general. The former, $f'(-x)$, means to take the derivative first, and plug in $-x$ second. For example,
$$f(x) = x^2 - x \implies f'(x) = 2x - 1 \implies f'(-x) = 2(-x) - 1 = -2x - 1.$$
The latter means plug in $-x$ first, then take the derivative, i.e.
$$f(x) = x^2 - x \implies f(-x) = (-x)^2 - (-x) = x^2 + x \implies (f(-x))' = 2x + 1.$$
The proof uses the notation $(f(x))'$ to make it clear that the derivative with respect to $x$ is being taken on both sides of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Put $h(x):=f(-x)$. If $f(x)=h(x)$, then $f'(x)=h'(x)=-f'(-x)$

The notation $(f(x))'$ means $f'(x)$, but this is not a good notation.